# C++ Qt and visual studio

Tags: c++, qt

after building Qt using Visual Studio command

I try to test my first application by this code :

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPushButton button("Hello world !");
    button.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

but I got this error:

Error   LNK1168 cannot open c:\Users\Maha\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\llolo\x64\Debug\llolo.exe for writing  llolo   c:\Users\Maha\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\llolo\llolo\LINK    1

Comment: It usually means your program is still running so the compiler could not delete it to create a new executable. The other option is your antivirus is causing that. Avast (and its sandbox mode) is known to cause many issues with Visual Studio and other compilers.

Comment: so  what i should do ?

Comment: Check to see if `llolo.exe` is running in task manager. Possibly disable your antivirus. A reboot can also fix this.

Comment: Open up your task manager, find the process and shut it down. Then try again.